# Python: List as function parameter

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
def test(mylist=['a']):  
        mylist.append(1.)  
        print mylist

test()  
test()
```

Is giving me the following result:

```
['a', 1.0]  
['a', 1.0, 1.0]
```

Why is this the case? I would expect:

```
['a', 1.0]  
['a', 1.0]
```

The test is called two times and eachtime mylist is created as a local variable.

Comment: See ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: The list is only created once at the function definition :) Never use a mutable datatype as default argument.

Comment: @ms4py -- never, unless you're intentionally using it as a cache across calls. A default argument of {} can be used for quick-and-dirty memoization, for instance.